# Find and show primitive element of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I have the polynomial $\ f(x)= x^{15}-3 $ and want to find the splitting field.
The splitting field is surely $\Bbb Q$ adjoined the roots of the polynomial. I want to write the splitting field as $\Bbb Q$ adjoined one element. How should I choose this element? How do I show that $\Bbb Q$ adjoined this element gives me the whole splitting field?

Comment: If you want to find a primitve element for the extension... Well, this is not so trivial. I suggest you to consider that the splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[15]{3}, e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{15}})$. This should be enough to describe degree, Galois group, etcetera.

Comment: Look at the roots of $x^{15}-3$ which are $\sqrt[15]{3} e^{\frac{2n\pi i}{15}}$ for $n=1,2,...,14,15$. Your goal is to find a linear combination of the roots such that all linear combinations of the powers of your element you picked give you all the rest.

Comment: @Crostul  I also would write the splitting field as you wrote it since it is wielder but finding the primitive element was an exercise given to me during an exam and will likely be on the next one.

Comment: The splitting field is certainly gotten by adjoining a single root $\lambda$ of $f$ and all the fifteenth roots of unity. As it happens, $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{15})\colon\Bbb Q]=8$, so that the degree of your extension is at most $8\cdot15=120$. It’s not at all clear (to me), however, that this is the degree. My strategy would be to determine the degree, and then try $\lambda+\zeta_{15}$ for a primitive element. This trick works surprisingly often!

Comment: Sorry, it’s now clear to me that the degree *is* $120$. Should be easy from here on in.